# if only usage: leave out the 'was'

Tags: grammar, terminology

When 'it' refers to a letter or a complex situation projected to be caused by a letter, is it okay to use 'if only' in the following way? Why or why not?

"It'd all be appropriate if only written by any other person."

I understand that I can always say "if only it was written by any other person", but that seems wordy.

I guess here, the 'it' could either refer to the letter or the situation caused by the letter, and I'm okay with either. But strictly speaking, perhaps only when you interpret the 'it' to mean the letter itself can you leave out the 'was'?

Comment: Yes, you should leave the *was* out — and use *were*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, followed by "as it were."

Comment: *if only* and *only if* are quite different in sense; I think you mean the latter.

Comment: If ‘it’ refers to a letter then you should not use ‘all’.

Comment: Does "it" refers to a letter that has already been written? Are you stating a hypothetical about the past? If so, then this calls for "it would've all been appropriate if it had been written by any other person".

Comment: @RosieF The letter has been written, but the situation is ongoing and involves an event that's going to happen in the future. That's why the speaker realizes that it's going to be a mess and says the line in question. Think of it as: someone submitted a speech for an event and the event organizers -- going through the speeches received -- realize he is the worst person to deliver that speech even though the speech itself is the best one they have.

Comment: @Jim True! If I want to use "all", and I do, then 'it' has to refer to the entire situation, not the letter.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Added some clarifications in the above comment re what the speaker is trying to achieve with that line. I want to express a wish for an alternative scenario rather than state a fact, and I want the irony to be there. Also, doesn't 'only if' sound just a bit too academic?

Comment: Okay, I see now that you do want *if only* — in the sense of wishing. *If only* is an idiom, and it needs to be followed by a full clause, and a subjunctive one, at that: *This letter would be appropriate if only it were written by someone else.* Or: *This whole situation would be appropriate if only that letter were written by someone else.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat I have a vague feeling that your conclusion that the clause can't be infinitival is right, at least that an infinitival clause makes the sense doubtful. But I can't find a reference. The would-be fact that the subjunctive is needed is very doubtful: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20only%20you%20had%20told%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en. (I would have understood if only you had told me the truth!)

Comment: @LPH: Your examples *are* subjunctive -- the past perfect subjunctive for counterfactuals in the past (warning: grammar terms vary). **"Past"** subjunctive for present counterfactuals: _This would be wonderful if only it **were** free._ [**"Past perfect"** subjunctive](https://www.grammaring.com/past-perfect-subjunctive) for past counterfactuals: _That would have been wonderful if only it **had been** free._

Comment: @TinfoilHat There is a problem; it seems that a new point of view has been added or has vied with another (perhaps more traditional); the terminology and description on which I brushed up briefly yields this: "The _were_ subjunctive (or past subjunctive) […] this subjunctive is limited to the one form _were_ […]" (CoGEL). This past perfective is then acknowledged further in the same reference as _hypothetical past perfective_. There appears to be a difference being made between _putative_ and _hypothetical_ meaning. (1/2)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Further still, in the same reference, can be read that "the past (or _were_) subjunctive is used in formal style in hypothetical conditional clauses […]. The were-subjunctive cannot replace the hypothetical past in constructions introduced by _It's time (that)_ (It's time I was in bed.)". (2/2)